# Karate: Get all users and delete with the reference id

Tags: karate

After my tests are completed, I would like to delete all the users that were created. I am able to delete one user at a time. Can we do this using conditional logic?

```
Feature file:

Given path  'users'
    And header Authorization = authId
    And header Accept = 'application/json;version=2'
    When method Get
    Then status 200
    Then print 'Response Time: '+ responseTime + ' milliseconds'
    * def resp = $
    * def size = karate.sizeOf(resp)
    * print 'Number of users: ' + size
```

This gives me below response:

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "Edit User",
    "lastName": "API Test",
    "emailAddress": "edituserapitesting@gmail.com",
    "ada": true,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "alerts": [],
    "links": [
      {
        "href": "https://someurl/api/users/0219360d-5ca6-42af-9e9c-10be1e32d219",
        "rel": "self"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Create",
    "lastName": "Test",
    "emailAddress": "api@test.com",
    "ada": true,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "alerts": [],
    "links": [
      {
        "href": "https://someurl/api/users/5e3c9be1-2863-4a2d-85e9-966582b127ac",
        "rel": "self"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Create",
    "lastName": "Test",
    "emailAddress": "api@test.com",
    "ada": true,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "alerts": [],
    "links": [
      {
        "href": "https://someurl/api/users/b6feb126-bca2-43e6-ba2d-87aaae81fef0",
        "rel": "self"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Create",
    "lastName": "Test",
    "emailAddress": "api@test.com",
    "ada": true,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "alerts": [],
    "links": [
      {
        "href": "https://someurl/api/users/4f07f234-9606-4cf5-94ce-3a42fb11a6d7",
        "rel": "self"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have to get the id [Eg:4f07f234-9606-4cf5-94ce-3a42fb11a6d7] from each json and pass it to delete path.

Comment: I have to get the id [Eg:4f07f234-9606-4cf5-94ce-3a42fb11a6d7]  which I can pass it to the delete http request 
http://someurl.com/api/users/4f07f234-9606-4cf5-94ce-3a42fb11a6d7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read about transforms: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

Now in one line you can get an array of ids:

```
* def ids = karate.map(response, function(x){ var link = x.links[0].href; return link.substring(link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) })
```

Now you can use this in a [loop](https://github.com/intuit/karate#loops) or data [driven test](https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features) and do what you want.