# Karate: Pass array into HTTP Request

Tags: karate

This is a continuation of this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58636764/karate-get-all-users-and-delete-with-the-reference-id).

I have tried loops and datadriven, all the ids are getting passed at a time into the delete request.

```
Scenario: Get all users
        #Get all users
        Given path  'users'
        And header Authorization = authId
        And header Accept = 'application/json;version=2'
        When method GET
        Then status 200
        * def userids = karate.map(response, function(x){ var link = x.links[0].href; return link.substring(link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) })
        Then print userids
        Given path 'users'
        And path {userid: '#(userids)'}
        When method DELETE
        Then status 204
```

I want to pass only one id from array at a time, send the request which will delete the user and again pass other id's till the array length is 1 in the same HTTP request.

Comment: no you have not tried data driven. please read it again. you will need a second feature file. also please see `karate.mapWithKey()` to convert the array of strings into an array of json objects. try again: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-mapwithkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me walk through a possible ways i can think of,

You can move userids list generation part to `Background:` and create a dynamic scenario outline with the `userIds` variable as input.

```
Feature : delete user

Background:
        * url baseUrl
        Given path  'users'
        And header Authorization = authId
        And header Accept = 'application/json;version=2'
        When method GET
        Then status 200
        * def userids = karate.map(response, function(x){ var link = x.links[0].href; return link.substring(link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) }) 
        * def userids = karate.mapWithKey(userids, "userId")

   Scenario Outline: Delete Users
        Given path 'users'
        And path userId
        When method DELETE
        Then status 204

        Examples:
            | userids |
```

Comment: Hi Babu, I have tried this already. It didn't work. Some junk value is getting passed into the request
url: https://someurl/api/users/%7B%22userid%22:%22userids%22%7D

instead of 
url: https://someurl/api/users/2185192a-0367-4189-832a-7c6228ccdc2b

Comment: My bad! We shouldn't pass json into path.. Just try `path userId`.

Comment: It didn't work. This is what it is coming now
https://someurl/api/users/userids

Comment: @sudheer check and try the updated answer. Make sure you are using latest version of karate as well